# Chrome Extension передача сообщений

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Столкнулся с еще одной проблемой при передаче сообщения (`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`) из `background script` в `content script` когда пользователь переходит между вкладками.

После первого перемещения между вкладками выдает ошибку `Extension context invalidated`.

Кто может помочь решить эту проблему?

**Background script**

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({tabId: activeInfo.tabId}, function(response) {
        changeBgIcon(response.status);
    });
});
```

**Content script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.tabId){
        sendResponse({status: window.localStorage.getItem('extension_rb_popup')});
    }
});
```

**Manifest json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Rebatemango Extension",
  "description": "Rebatemango",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js",
        "g_search.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "cookies",
    "tabCapture",
    "displaySource"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/jquery.js",
      "js/libs.js",
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/mango.png",
    "48": "images/mango.png",
    "128": "images/mango.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, бэкграунд-скрипт уже выгружен на момент отправки сообщения... С изменением значения параметра `persistent` на `true` - проблема сохраняется?

Comment: @yar85 да та же проблема. прочитал что порт закрывается. но все таки не могу решить проблему. не где не нахожу ни одного такого примера или дока.
как будто я первый кто хочет такое сделать.

Comment: Хм, тогда я не знаю (ранее не сталкивался с подобным). Могу только предложить передачу данных через `chrome.storage` - у него есть возможность подписки на изменения в слушателях на `onChanged`.

Comment: @yar85 Можете подсказать как взять `localstorage` текущей вкладки (не расширения) из background script.?

Comment: Из бэкграунд-скрипта точно никак, потому что `localStorage` это часть DOM... а к модели документа имеют доступ только контент-скрипты (если в новых версиях Хрома еще не ужесточили правила безопасности). По идее можно взять данные из `localStorage` контент-скриптом и им же записать в `chrome.storage` (в бэкграунд-скрипте подписавшись на изменения). Лучше конечно сообщением передать эти данные, но учитывая проблему в вопросе, остается только такой вариант...